# How do I export an iFrame to PDF

Tags: reactjs, iframe, export-to-pdf

I am using an iFrame to display an URL of an existing website and would like to export the contents of that iFrame to a PDF page/pages.

But as soon as I click on the Export button it downloads a blank PDF page.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  } 

  exportPDF = () => {
        this.myHTML.save();
    }

  render() {
    return (

      <div id='page'>
      <div>
          <button onClick={this.exportPDF} className="snip1303 ion-ios-home-outline">Export</button>
      </div>
      <br /><br />
          <PDFExport paperSize={'Letter'}
                        fileName="myPDF.pdf"
                        title=""
                        subject=""
                        keywords=""
                        ref={(r) => this.myHTML = r}>
                        <div style={{
                            height: 842,
                            width: 700,
                            marginBottom: 20,
                            padding: 'none',
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            boxShadow: '5px 5px 5px black',
                            margin: 'auto',
                            overflowX: 'hidden',
                            overflowY: 'hidden'
                        }}>      
              <Iframe id="frame" 
              url="https://www.smartpractice.co.za"
              width="700px"
              height="840px"        
              display=""
              class="myClassname"
              position="absolute"
              title="PDF_View" /> 
              </div>
          </PDFExport>           
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening and what I can do to correct this.

Thanx.

Comment: What is the `<PDFExport>` component? Did you import it from an external library, or did you write your own?

Comment: I imported it from an external library. Here is a link to the code on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sp?embed=1&file=index.js